How wrong does using future instead of future perfect ("The test will start at 9 AM and it will not end before 11 AM.") sound?
I know that it is corect to say "The test starts at 9 AM and it will not have ended before 11 AM.". But, I was wondering, how wrong does "The test will start at 9 AM and it will not end before 11 AM." (a literal translation from Croatian "Test će početi u 9 sati i neće završiti prije 11 sati.") sound? I suppose you would be understood if you said that, right? If so, how wrong would you sound?

Why do you think the second is wrong? I will go at 10 am and will not go before that. You tell us why will/will might be wrong according to you. They  mean two different things.

There's no problem with the use of the future.  Present tense might be chosen because the test is following a timetable or schedule, but it is rarely wrong to use "will" to talk about future events.
Saying "Will not end before 11" is also correct.  In context, it seems odd to say when the test will not end (or will not have ended).  It would be more common to say when the test will end.

In OP's context, presumably the "default" end time is in fact 11, but there might be reasons why it could be extended. In which case taking account of your final sentence, the best way to express it might be ...will end no earlier than 11 AM
